# How do I compare two simple Dictionaries using BeEquivalentTo from FluentAssertions?

Tags: fluent-assertions

I've created the following very simple test which is a simplification of a scenario I've come across in the wild.

```
var actual = new JObject
{
    {"prop1" , "1"},
    {"prop2" , "2"},
};

var expected = new JObject
{
    {"prop1" , "3"},
    {"prop2" , "2"},
};

actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

I have two JObjects which differ at a single key and I would like a test to fail if they differ and tell me where the difference is.

This passes but I wouldn't expect it to because of the difference I've already mentioned. I've spend quite a bit of time messing around with customizing the equivalency check with no luck. Hopefully someone can point out what I've overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

> You can also assert the equality of the entire dictionary, where the equality of the keys and values will be validated using their Equals implementation.

Reference [FluentAssertions - Dictionaries](https://fluentassertions.com/dictionaries/)

Like

```
actual.Should().Equal(expected);
```

Comment: Thanks. Was embarrasingly obvious. I was fixated on getting the wrong method to work.